# Setting "Additional Field Options" for thumbnails in Voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

I would like to use thumbnails in my blog posts. In the Post-model I need to write this:

```
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Resizable;

class Post extends Model
{
    use Resizable;
}
```

Then there is an other settings piece:

```
{
    "resize": {
        "width": "1000",
        "height": null
    },
    "quality" : "70%",
    "upsize" : true,
    "thumbnails": [
        {
            "name": "medium",
            "scale": "50%"
        },
        {
            "name": "small",
            "scale": "25%"
        },
        {
            "name": "cropped",
            "crop": {
                "width": "300",
                "height": "250"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Where does the settings part go?**

**And, how do I generate the thumbnails after that?**

Sources:

https://voyager.readme.io/docs/thumbnails-url

https://voyager.readme.io/docs/additional-field-options#section-image

Answer (score 1):

Settings should be written in the BREAD page for your table in front of the image form field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this is so long ago, and I honestly don't even know what I was trying to solve then and if it is solved already. I give you an upvote for your effort.